Can use one-variable integration to tell whether $R=\{(x,y):\;0\leq y\leq\left|\mathrm{sin}\frac{1}{x}|,\;0<x\ <1\right\}$ is rectifiable(has area)?
$R=\left\{(x,y):\;0\leq y\leq\left|\mathrm{sin}\frac{1}{x}\right|,\;0<x\ <1\right\}$, to determine whether it's rectifiable, can I use the method of one-variable integration to prove? Like this question, if we see it as a one-variable integration $f(x)=\int_0^1 |\sin(\frac{1}{x})|$, then it has only one discontinuous point at (0,0), so it's integrable. Can I use this to tell that R is rectifiable?
If using the def. of rectifiable(or has area), we need to take partition first and check the area of $\partial D$ has zero area, but it's not so simple to handle the discontinuity at $(0,0)$. So I hope the question can be converted into the integration on the x,y plane.
I guess it's OK, but I don't know how to prove it.

Can you answer the question for $R_\epsilon = R\cap {x\ge\epsilon}$? What can you say about the remainder of the region?

Let $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) = |\sin \frac{1}{x}|$ for $0 < x \leqslant 1$. Note that $f$ is bounded and Riemann integrable on $[0,1].$ Given a partition $P: 0 = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = 1$, the lower and upper Darboux sums are given by
$$L(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^nm_j(x_j - x_{j-1}),\quad U(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^nM_j(x_j - x_{j-1})$$
where $m_j = \inf\{f(x): x_{j-1} \leqslant x \leqslant x_j\}$ and $M_j = \sup\{f(x): x_{j-1} \leqslant x \leqslant x_j\}$.  Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ such that
$$U(P,f) - L(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n (M_j-m_j)(x_j - x_{j-1})< \epsilon$$
But the above expression is just the sum of the areas of rectangles $Q_j =[x_{j-1},x_j]\times [m_j,M_j]$ where  $j=1,2,\ldots,n$ and such that
$$B = \{|f(x)|:0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1\}\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n Q_j$$
Since $\epsilon$ can be taken as small as we like, we have shown that the upper boundary of the region $R$ can be covered with a finite number of rectangles of arbitrarily small total area, and, hence, must have zero content. The other segments that form the boundary of $r$ are easily shown to have zero content. Therefore, the region $R$ is rectifiable.
